# javascript - export default types

Tags: javascript

I'm aware you can do the following:

```
const foo = (bar) => { //some code... };
const baz = () => { //some code... };
export default { foo, baz, ... }
```

or

```
export default {
  foo: (bar) => //some code,
  baz: () => //some code,
  ...
}
```

Is there an advantage of one over the other, or is it merely a preference style?

Comment: Two different styles, same outcome.

Comment: The first would be useful if other code in the module needed to use `foo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first example you can access both functions , like

```
const foo = (bar) => { //some code... };
const baz = () => { foo(); //some code that uses foo() };
export default { foo, baz, ... }
```

in the second one , you can't.

Answer (score 1):

It is all preference. The first is a bit more readable, in my opinion. Declare your variables and then export the ones that you need. If you decide to split up your exports than the second wouldn't really work all too well.